# Get videos on special (curated) channels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube V3 API and attempting to get the list of videos on the channel [#PopularOnYouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA). For all regular channels this works easily by using the search API and providing the channelId parameter. But for some reason these special YouTube curated channels do not behave like all the other YouTube channels. Is their some special way you have to go about getting the list of videos on these special channels?

This also replicated (does not work) when using their [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it), but will work fine for regular channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some doing, but I think I found the answer. Since a curated channel's videos aren't necessarily considered to be "uploaded", you have to look for its channel sections as opposed to an upload playlist.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channelSections?part=snippet,contentDetails,id&channelId=UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA&key=API_KEY
```

From this, I get the playlist ID based on the channel's "Popular right now" channel section (which had channelSection ID `UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA.7e4CTK8-inw` and is technically different from a playlist):  `PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-`.

Using that playlist ID, I made a `playlistItems` list request to get that playlist's videos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails,id&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key=API_KEY
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit out my second channelSection call. I'm not sure if there's a way to tell if it's a curated channel or not programmatically, so you might have to do it the way you mentioned if you're really hard-pressed. In the `channels.list` call, I see there's a `status` field. Maybe you could submit a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list) asking to add a field to `status` that tells if it's a curated channel or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get PopularOnYoutube's playlist by using the search API, then you can use PlaylistItems:list to get the videos for each playlist

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't see any playlists that contain the same content as the list of uploaded videos. I am essentially trying to get the same content provided here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA/videos

Comment: For every other channel other then these special ones search with type video for the channel id does the trick. But not for these YouTube curated ones.

Comment: Maybe you could get by this https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=us&key= but the problem is that u need to choose a region.